Unable to get events form google calendar in FullCalendar REACTJS
I'm attempting to integrate Google Calendar events into my React application using FullCalendar, but despite following the documentation closely and setting my calendar to public, I haven't been able to successfully retrieve events. Here's the relevant code snippet:
           ` <FullCalendar
                ref={calendarRef}
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin,timeGridPlugin,googleCalendarPlugin]}
                googleCalendarApiKey=API_KEY
                initialView="dayGridMonth"
                weekends={true}
                dateClick={handleDateClick}
                headerToolbar={false}
               eventSources = {[{ 
                googleCalendarId : 'tes@gmail.ae'      
               }]}
                height='70vh' />`

I've ensured that my Google Calendar is set to public, and I've replaced 'YOUR_API_KEY' and 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID' with my actual API key and calendar ID respectively. However, no events are being displayed.
I've verified that the API key is correct and that the calendar ID points to the correct calendar. Is there something I might be missing or any additional steps I should take to troubleshoot this issue?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I'd start by checking if any requests to Google are being made, and what response they get.

You should make a rest request with postman or thunder client to see if your request is returning successfully before any debugging.

@CBroe thanks for your reply .. i just fixed it by  add the googleCalendarApiKey inside the  eventSources..

@SaudAhmad Glad you fixed it...but: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not part of the question! Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because to the search engine it looks like (part of) a question. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The Can I answer my own question? and [answer] articles from the help centre are also relevant. Thanks.
